# Clojure deftype: how to constrain field types?

Tags: java, clojure, clojure-java-interop

I'm trying to write a Clojure library that can be used from Java without users knowing it is written in Clojure. For this, I need my fields to have proper types:

I like that I can do this:

```
(deftype Point [^double x ^double y])
```

Which generates a class with proper types for x/y. However, this only seems to work for primitives, not for classes:

```
(deftype Foo [^String bar])
```

Generates a:

```
public final Object bar;
```

where I would expect a:

```
public final String bar;
```

Is there a way to constrain the field types? Is there another option outside of `deftype`/`defrecord`?

Comment: Are you sure it's not easier just to declare your types in java? Presumably, to preserve the 'users don't know it's clojure' you'll want to generate javadocs etc. Defining thin interfaces, value types etc. in java and then extend them as necessary in the clojure domain?

Answer (score 12):

From http://clojure.org/datatypes on `deftype` and `defrecord`:

> fields can have type hints, and can be primitive
>
> note that **currently a type hint of a non-primitive type**
>    **will not be used to constrain the field type** nor the 
>    constructor arg, but will be used to optimize its use in
>    the class method
>
> constraining the field type and constructor arg is planned

(my emphasis)

Comment: So there is no way to constrain the field type?

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do that using deftype alone. Your options here are either implement a typed java Interface using proxy/reify (meaning you must use only methods as your public API), or use gen-class if you really need typed, public fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to do in this way: `(deftype Point [#^Integer x #^Integer y])`

Comment: I tested this and it seems that "#^Integer" does exactly the same as "^Integer".

Comment: Those are the same thing - #^ is the old syntax and ^ is the new syntax.